# How to make a page refresh everyday at 6 and 7

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery and the interval function is their anyway that I could refresh my page at 6 and 7 everyday or would I need to use another method that could be better?

Comment: @Joe SNow, What have you tired so far ?
Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan the OP has asked for everyday and 6-7 is the time of the day or eve

Comment: I have different parts of the page that change at different parts of the day. My charts only need to be updataed at 6 and 7 am .

Comment: Refer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time)

Answer (score 0):

for something such custom requirement

You need something like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function(){
           var dt = new Date();
           var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
           $gethour = dt.getHours();
           if($gethour=="18" || $gethour=="06" || $gethour=="19" || $gethour=="07" ){
            // post your code here 
            window.location.reload();
        }
    },1000);
    });
</script>
```

this might work for you :)