# How can i refresh a page with a wait of 100 seconds javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, reload, page-refresh

How can i refresh a page with a wait of **100 seconds** in javascript.

i used

```
location.reload();
```

but i need to wait for 100 seconds before reloading

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 100000}`

Comment: Note that `setTimeout` is not a very precise thing. Setting it to `100000` will probably be close to 100 seconds, but does not guarantee it. Especially, if it is run in the background tab or on a client with the lack of resources.

Comment: See the previous discussed thread..
Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   location.reload(); 
},100000);
```

Answer (score 4):

To reload a page, you don't want to use second argument

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="100" />
```

Reload a page every 100 seconds