# How to Refresh page at particular time

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript to refresh my page at 5:25 pm EST.
For example if a user come to my page at 5.00pm EST and he stay at 5.40pm EST let suppose.Then I want to refresh my page at 5.25pm EST.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to check time at specific intervals and if desired time is reached, just use [`location.reload`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp):

```
window.setInterval(funciton() {
  var now = new Date();
  if(now.getTime() == SOMETHING) {
    location.reload();
  }
}, REFRESH_INTERVAL);
```

If you want to use time zone calculation, etc. I suggest [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

**UPDATE**:

There is a nice snippet provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1217945/2295964), which does it more elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute time to reload and then set timeout function to reload page:

```
var now = new Date()
var timeOfRefresh = new Date();
timeOfRefresh.setHours(5);
timeOfRefresh.setMinutes(25);
timeOfRefresh.setSeconds(0);
var diff = timeOfRefresh.getTime() - now.getTime();
if (diff < 0) { // is after 5:25
    diff += 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // refresh next day
}
setTimeout(location.reaload, diff);
```

Comment: Much easier than my solution!