# Highlight text at specific time of day

Tags: javascript, html

I need to highlight text at a specific time.

```
<style>
.highlight { 
background-color:#FFFF00; 
}
</style>
<span class="timer">Hello World</span>
<script> 
var date = new Date();
var minute = date.getMinutes();
var hour = date.getHours();


if(
        (hour >= 9 && minute >= 59) &&
        (hour <= 10 && minute <= 59)
    ){
           $('timer').addClass('highlight');
    }
</script>
```

In the above example, it should highlight "Hello World" between 10:00 and 11:00.
This isn't working - any thoughts?

Comment: you need to reload a page after specific x seconds to get to know when time is your specified than change color.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time

Comment: that's true if he wants it to update in real time, but it's not the core issue - the if statement logic is faulty. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like A. Damond said your `if` statement is only true if your time is either 9:59 or 10:59.

I would change your `if` statement to:

```js
var date = new Date();
var minute = date.getMinutes();
var hour = date.getHours();


if ((hour === 10)) {
  $('.timer').addClass('highlight');
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timer">Hello World</span>
```

Also you have to add the right selector in your jQuery `addClass` call.
`$('.timer')` not `$('timer')`.

**EDIT** I've updated the if clause

Comment: ah yeah good catch - didn't even notice the incorrect selector

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is equivalent to doing the same thing without parentheses. So you're checking to see if the hour is *both* greater than or equal to 9 *and* less than or equal to 10 (which will only be true if the hour is either 9 or 10) and also if the minute is *both* greater than or equal to 59 *and* less than or equal to 59 (which will only happen if the minute is exactly 59). So your `if` statement is only going to return `true` if your time is either 9:59 or 10:59.

Why not just use `if (hour === 10)`?

Comment: I also nee dthe minutes like 10:30 - 10:45

Comment: @Mezz the minute isn't relevant. If the hour is 10 the `if` statement is always correct. Whether 10:30, 10:45 or 10:59.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because in the jQuery selector you have to put a 'dot'.

```
$('.timer').addClass('highlight');
```

when you want select an id, just put

```
$('#timer').addClass('highlight');
```

As @Damon has suggested, it's simpler if you just check only the hour

```
(=== 10 || (=== 11 && minute === 00)) // this will include also the 11:00
```

Of course, if final user opens the page (at 10) and he/she never updates/reloads, the background will be always visible, or the opposite, if he opens the page at 9. 
To do a job well done and working properly, you have to introduce a clock on the page and this can be a good example:
http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2010/08/javascript-clock/