# Auto Refresh at the top of every hour

Tags: html, refresh

This is what I've already tried:

```
<meta name="Refresh" content="3600">
```

What would be the best way to go about making a HTML page automatically refresh at 12am PT every day? Or if that's not possible, the top of every hour like 1am, 2am, 3am and so on. Not an hour from when the user loads the page but the top of the next hour.

Everything I've tried so far seems to just refresh every hour from when the page was loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically reload a web page at a certain time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time)

Comment: that goes off the users timezone tho. i need it to refresh at the top of every hour regardless of timezones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with HTML alone. You need Javascript, but it's very easy. Just add this to your HTML:

```
<script>
    var current = new Date();
    var future = new Date();
    future.setTime(future.getTime() + 3600000); //3600000 = 1 hour
    future.setMinutes(0);
    future.setSeconds(0);

    var timeout = (future.getTime() - current.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
</script>
```

Comment: Will that Reset at the top of every hour or  1 hour from when the user first loads the page? like lets say they load the page at 12:36 pm i need it to refresh at 1 pm not 1:36 pm

Comment: @BryanSMith This code should refresh at the top of the next hour, so if the user loads the page at 12:36pm it will refresh at 1:00pm, then 2:00pm and so on.

Comment: @BryanSMith No worries, glad to help. Don't forget to accept this as the correct answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="3600">
```

Add this to your head.

Answer (score 0):

This will refresh on the top of the hour, every hour

```js
let now = new Date()
let nextHour = new Date(now)
nextHour.setHours(now.getHours() + 1,0,0,0)
let delay = nextHour.getTime() - now.getTime()
setTimeout(()=>{window.location.reload(true)}, delay)
```

This has to be in the  tag, after all the meta tags
To view this in the console, use:

```
console.log('Some crazy numbers '+delay+ '. Next refresh time '+nextHour +' current time '+ now)
```

After the previous code