# refresh page at a specific time

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop

hear me out. suppose a page has to be reloaded every weekday at 9:30 am. the page is opened at 9 am. so at 9:15 am the page should automatically get  reloaded without any user intervention. what can be done. any help is appreciated

```
 function checkTime() {
        var d = new Date(); // current time
        var hours = d.getHours();
         var mins = d.getMinutes();
         if (hours >= 17 || hours <= 18) {
          setInterval(() => {
           location.reload();
             }, 5000);

                   }

                }
```

Comment: Your approach is fine in principle, is just badly indented and wrong when it comes to the details. The first problem is `hours >= 17 || hours <= 18` because that's true for any number. You also need to put the time check inside the interval, not the other way around.

Comment: Like this basically: https://jsfiddle.net/qwehkv0n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've asked the question as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217929/how-to-automatically-reload-a-web-page-at-a-certain-time#:%7E:text=onload%20%3D%20beginrefresh%3B,can%27t%20do%20anything%20more.).

But to help you quickly, I've copied the code.

```
function refreshAt(hours, minutes, seconds) {
    var now = new Date();
    var then = new Date();

    if(now.getHours() > hours ||
       (now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() > minutes) ||
        now.getHours() == hours && now.getMinutes() == minutes && now.getSeconds() >= seconds) {
        then.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
    }
    then.setHours(hours);
    then.setMinutes(minutes);
    then.setSeconds(seconds);

    var timeout = (then.getTime() - now.getTime());
    setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, timeout);
}
```

### Then you can add a script tag to call the refreshAt() function.

```
refreshAt(15,35,0); //Will refresh the page at 3:35pm
```

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/26210/andrew-moore

Comment: If there's an existing answer (there always is), don't post your own under the new question but flag it as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Chris. So should I do it now?

Comment: While it's a duplicate I disagree with the accepted answer. Especially when it comes to greater numbers, setInterval can be unreliable. I'd actually prefer the approach OP chose: use a small interval to keep checking the time, and reload if the point in time has passed.